# Gitlab: can I configure a served javascript file to be served as the client can execute it?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-api

Version control repositories started to serve raw files as `text/plain` and to add the header `content-type-options: nosniff` so they can't be used as static hosting. I have an internal GitLab installation that I want to use to host some javascript (it would be used to access GitLab own API).

Is it possible to serve a raw file as Javascript?  I'd like to turnoff the http header or change the mime-type of the serverd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to serve directly from the repository, since GitLab won't serve the correct mime type. If you want to do it, you probably need to use [GitLab Pages](https://about.gitlab.com/product/pages/).